# CTest - Using Labels for different tests CTestTestfile.cmake

Tags: cmake, ctest

I cannot find how to specify labels. It should be something like

```
ADD_TEST( FirstTest RunSomeProgram "withArguments" )
SET_TESTS_PROPERTIES( FirstTest PROPERTIES LABEL "TESTLABEL" )
```

Can someone tell me how I can set one of these labels, that I can access using the

```
ctest -S someScript -L TESTLABEL
```

Answer (score 22):

You're close - the test property is named [`LABELS`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_test/LABELS.html), not `LABEL`.

There are a couple of ways of setting labels; the one you've chosen (using [`set_tests_properties`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_tests_properties.html)) has a slight gotcha.  The signature is:

```
set_tests_properties(test1 [test2...] PROPERTIES prop1 value1 prop2 value2)
```

This means that each property can only have a single value applied.  So if you want to apply multiple labels to tests this way, you need to "trick" CMake by passing the list of labels as a single string comprising a semi-colon-separated list:

```
set_tests_properties(FirstTest PROPERTIES LABELS "TESTLABEL;UnitTest;FooModule")
```

or

```
set(Labels TESTLABEL UnitTest FooModule)
set_tests_properties(FirstTest PROPERTIES LABELS "${Labels}")  # Quotes essential
```

On the other hand, you can pass a proper list of labels using the more general [`set_property`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_property.html) command:

```
set_property(TEST FirstTest PROPERTY LABELS TESTLABEL UnitTest FooModule)
```

or

```
set_property(TEST FirstTest PROPERTY LABELS ${Labels})  # No quotes needed
```

The slight downside of this command is that you can only apply one property per call.